# Mule: reuse a foreach payload and run it again through another foreach component

Tags: csv, foreach, mule, reusability, payload

I have a simple csv-to-pojo datamapper, which gets sent to two synchronous flow through an "All" flow control component. The first flow runs the payload through a Foreach, then once it is done, the second flow attempts to run the payload from the datamapper again through a different foreach, but instead I'm getting this warning message:

```
Splitter returned no results. If this is not expected, please check your split expression.
```

Furthermore, it seems that Mule only allows me to run the payload through either flow one or flow two, but not both. Again, running it trough more than one Foreach component will result in the Splitter warning.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here's the setup:

```
<flow name="main_flow" doc:name="main_flow" initialState="started" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="csv_to_pojo" doc:name="CSV To Pojo" stream="true"/>
    <all doc:name="All">
         <flow-ref name="flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
         <flow-ref name="flow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
    </all>
</flow>

<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <logger message="Entering flow 1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <logger message="Inside foreach of flow1 " level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>

<flow name="flow2" doc:name="flow2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <logger message="Entering flow2" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <logger message="Inside foreach of flow2" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Comment: The flow you provided works fine for me. Mule 3.5. Is there anything missing in this flow than from your original flow.

Comment: What happens if you use scatter-gather instead of all?

Comment: @user1760178 Your datamapper (csv-to-pojo and collection of objects) is actually passed to each Foreach? I'm using Mule 3.5 as well. I'm using an FTP file watcher, and when it finds a csv file it gives it to the datamapper (csv-to-pojo) and that's about it.

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev scatter-gather? You mean a message chunk aggregator?

Comment: I mean this, which sends copies of message to all routes at once for parallel asynchronous execution: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scatter-Gather